# Visual Studio 2019 C# WCF Test Client not working with svcutil.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, svcutil.exe, wcftestclient

I have an WCF Test Client application which was originally created in Visual Studio 2017 which worked fine, however once I upgraded my Visual Studio to 2019 and re-ran the application, I get the following error message:
The dependent tool 'svcutil.exe' is not found [image].

Note, I checked and svcutil.exe exists in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools

Any idea why it is no longer working?

Comment: VS2019 shipped before 4.8 was available, it used 4.7.2 tooling.  No real idea if an update fixes this, but the next thing to try.

Answer (score 1):

i met the same problem, and solve it by installed the .NET Framework SDK 4.7.2, hope it will help.